# Expect script file name too long when writing to a file

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm new to coding and this is my first script. It works up to the point where it has to open(create) the file to write in. It then fails giving me an error somepassedNickvariable.txt file name too long. I run it as the user "qbot".

Sample output for the first expect:

```
2016-08-05T23:32:42 73600,565 INF Chat: 'Quadro': !ustawdomek
```

Sample output for the second one:

```
1. id=51890, Pepesza, pos=(473,1, 42,1, 1223,7), rot=(-66,1, 104,1, 0,0), remote=True, health=97, deaths=6, zombies=138, players=1, score=109, level=35, steamid=xxx, ip=xx.xx.xx.xx, ping=111
2. id=1141, Quadro, pos=(465,6, 87,1, -624,1), rot=(-30,9, 1620,0, 0,0), remote=True, health=187, deaths=1, zombies=525, players=0, score=520, level=84, steamid=xxx, ip=xx.xx.xx.xx, ping=24
Total of 6 in the game
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can't get it to work by myself.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1
spawn telnet localhost 8081
expect "Please enter password" {sleep 3; send "blahblah\r" }

while {1} {
expect \
{
  "*INF Chat: '*': !ustawdomek" {
            regexp {'(.+)':\s\!ustawdomek} $expect_out(buffer) match Nick;
            set listplayers "*Total of * in the game";
            send "lp\r"
            expect $listplayers {
regexp "$Nick\,\\spos\=\\(\(\(\[-\]\?\\d+\)\,\\d\,\\s\(\[-\]\?\\d+\)\,\\d\,\\s\(\[-\]\?\\d+\)\,\\d\)\\)" $expect_out(buffer) match lok lok1 lok2 lok3
                    set file [open "/home/qbot/domki/$Nick.txt" w]
                    puts $file "$lok1 $lok2 $lok3"
                    close $file
                    send "pm $Nick \"\[QBOT\]Blahblah\"\r" }

             }
   timeout {break}
   eof {break}
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out what is in `$Nick`, to validate your assumption that it's a reasonably short string? The problem is likely not that the filename is too long per se, but that the regular expression isn't matching what you think it's matching.

Comment: I did,and it returned just what's between the two apostrophes in { 2016-08-05T23:32:42 73600,565 INF Chat: 'Quadro': !ustawdomek } . Well,got it to work,thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't entirely understand this script's syntax. But I guess it has something to do with the `regexp {'(.+)':\s\!ustawdomek} $expect_out(buffer) match Nick;`
`.+` as such is a greedy regular expression and should be avoided as long as possible. I think it's trying to match a very large filename. Try to use a simpler regexp that allows only word matches and possibly limit the size of filename. For instance, `\w{1,25}` or something like that.

Comment: What does this have to do with bash?

Comment: I thought that's the language this script is written in. Just saw the tag, its in TCL. I edited my comment above.

Comment: The first line is `#!/usr/bin/expect`. It's an expect script.

Comment: The contents of $Nick variable look fine just before executing [open "/home/qbot/domki/$Nick.txt w] but i'll try your solution

Comment: Not sure if that did it because i made some other changes without testing it first,but works now. Thanks for the help! :)